# How ot map docker container ip to a host ip (NAT instead of NAPT)?

Tags: docker, nat

The main goal is to do a real NAT instead of NAPT. Note normal `docker run -p ip:port2:port1` command actally is doing NAPT (address+port translation) instead of NAT(address translation). Is it possible to map address only, but keep all exposed ports the same as the container, like `docker run -p=ip1:*:* ...` , instead of one by one or a range?

ps.1. My port range is rather big (22-50070, ssh-hdfs) so port range approach won't work.
ps.2.  Maybe I need a swarm of virtual machines and join the host into the swarm.

ps.3 I raised [an feature request on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34453). Not sure if they will accept it but currently there are 2000+ open issues (it's so popular).

### Solution

On linux, you can access any container by ip and port without any binding (no `-p`) ootb. Docker version: CE 17+

If your host is windows, and docker is running on a linux VM like me, to access the containers, the only thing need to do is adding the route on windows `route add -p 172.16.0.0 mask 255.240.0.0 ip_of_your_vm`. Now you can access all containers by IP:port without any port mapping from both windows host and linux VM.

Comment: This would mean loosing every port on your HOST and even the SSH one. So why should be one following this approach?

Comment: You can use idle ip address. It does not affect any host port. This is much better than the default port mapping approach.

Comment: So you do have a idle IP available. A IPTables based solution works for you?

Comment: You can add many IPs to your eth0. I have not tried iptables yet. I'm running docker on win10.

Answer (score 5):

There are few options you have. One is to decide which PORT range you want to map then use that in your docker run

```
docker run -p 192.168.33.101:80-200:80-200 <your image>
```

Above will map all ports from `80` to `200` on your container. Assuming your idle IP is `192.168.33.100`. But unfortunately it is not possible to map a larger port range as docker creates multiple iptables forks to setup the tables and bombs the memory. It would raise an error like below

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint zen_goodall (0ae6cec360831b46fe3668d6aad9f5f72b6dac5d26cc6c817452d1402d12f02c):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 8513 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8513 ! -i docker0:  (fork/exec /sbin/iptables: resource temporarily unavailable)).
```

This is not right way of docker mapping it. But this is not a use case that they would agree to, so may not fix the above issue. Next option is to run your docker container without any port publishing and use below iptables rules

```
DOCKER_IP=172.17.0.2
ACTION=A
IP=192.168.33.101

sudo iptables -t nat -$ACTION DOCKER -d $IP -j DNAT --to-destination $DOCKER_IP ! -i docker0
sudo iptables -t filter -$ACTION DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d $DOCKER_IP -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -$ACTION POSTROUTING -p tcp -s $DOCKER_IP -d $DOCKER_IP -j MASQUERADE
```

`ACTION=A` will add the rules and `ACTION=D` will delete the rules. This would setup complete traffic from your `IP` to the `DOCKER_IP`. This only good if you are doing it on a testing server. Not recommended on staging or production. Docker adds a lot more rules to prevent other containers poking into your container but this offers no protection whatsoever

Comment: Swarm is not I wanted. I moved to  Linux and I can directly access the IP (172.xx:xxx) on linux,  this is OK for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a direct way to do what you are asking. 
If you use "-P" option with "docker run", all ports that are exposed using "EXPOSE" in Dockerfile will automatically get exposed with random ports in the host. With "-p" option, the only way is to specify the option multiple times for multiple ports.

Comment: Does "random ports" means totally random port, or it tries the same port first, if occupied then use random one?

Comment: I have seen the port usage is sequential even though the documentation says random. I dont think we should rely on any sequence and port number reuse. The port range is defined in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range.